# How to run PVS Studio from command line from Windows 7?

Tags: c, pvs-studio

I'm new to PVS Studio. I've installed it in Standalone mode (without Visual Studio). I would like to run PVS Studio from command line (from Cygwin64 Terminal) from Windows 7 Professional 64-bit. I want to statically analyze only one file 'main.c'. I use official documentation: https://www.viva64.com/ru/m/0006/#ID0E2H. I want to check simple code snippet, located in my test file 'main.c':

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    printf("%s: test message; 'a': '%d'; 'b': '%d'\n",
        __FUNCTION__, a, b, (a + b));
    return 0;
}
```

My code snippet was successfully compiled by 'mingw32-make.exe'.
I've run these commands from command line (from Cygwin64 Terminal in user mode, not in administrator mode):

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/PVS-Studio/x64
./PVS-Studio.exe --cl-params "C:\\all\\projects\\c\\pvs_studio\\2\\main.c" /D"x64" /I"C:\\all\\projects\\c\\pvs_studio\\2" --source-file "C:\\all\\projects\\c\\pvs_studio\\2\\main.c" --cfg "C:\\all\\projects\\c\\pvs_studio\\2\\PVS-Studio.cfg" --output-file "c:\\all\\projects\\c\\pvs_studio\\2\\output.txt"
```

Contents of the file 'PVS-Studio.cfg':

```
vcinstalldir = C:\all\soft\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
platform = x64
preprocessor = gcc
language = C
```

Contents of the file 'output.txt':

```
Viva64-EM
<#~>full
<#~>1
<#~>c:\all\projects\c\pvs_studio\2\main.c
<#~>error
<#~>V008
<#~>Unable to start the analysis on this file. Preprocessor exit code: 1.
<#~>false
<#~>0
<#~><#~><#~><#~>
```

Error 'V008' was occurred. How to fix this error ? I've read this documentation: https://www.viva64.com/ru/w/v008/, but don't understand where is an error ?

Comment: "How to run" is not a question, but a noun phrase.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting 'vcinstalldir' to 'C:\all\soft\mingw\bin\' - this param should point to the compiler's install directory instead of the compiler's full path. If you still have V008 errors after that, check analyzer's process stdErr, it should contain additional information about why preprocessing could have failed.

Alternatively, you could just run the preprocessing by yourself, and pass the resulting preprocessed file to the analyzer through the 'i-file' param. In this case, you should also pass the 'skip-cl-exe = yes' in the config. This way allows you to control preprocessing by yourself.